# How can I trigger custom code when some other module is being installed/uninstalled?

Tags: 7, installation

I am using a third-party module. Whenever it is installed or un-installed, I want to programmatically create/delete some menus.

How can I detect that a module is installed or un-installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hook_modules_installed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_installed/7.x) to react to modules being installed, e.g.

```
function hook_modules_installed($modules) {
  if (in_array('lousy_module', $modules)) {
    variable_set('lousy_module_conflicting_variable', FALSE);
  }
}
```

and [`hook_modules_uninstalled()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_uninstalled/7.x) to react to the opposite, e.g.

```
function hook_modules_uninstalled($modules) {
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
    db_delete('mymodule_table')
      ->condition('module', $module)
      ->execute();
  }
  mymodule_cache_rebuild();
}
```

Comment: This is working, and in my case, I need to use hook_modules_disabled() and hook_modules_enabled(). Yes, Thanks for pointing me in right direction.